# Debug a remote python file using Spyder

Tags: python, ide, spyder, remote-server

I am successfully able to connect to a remote kernel from my Spyder console using [these instructions](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/ipythonconsole.html?highlight=ssh#connect-to-a-remote-kernel).
Now I would like to know how if it is possible to open a .py file from a remote server and debug it inside Spyder on my local machine, and if yes how?
Spyder's file browser still browses for local machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You said

> I would like to know how if it is possible to open a .py file from a remote server and debug it inside Spyder on my local machine

Unfortunately, Spyder can't do that for you at the moment.

A workaround is to mount the remote directory where you have your file locally and then open it in Spyder. For that you can use [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) or [sshfs-win](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win), depending on your operating system.